# Reference top (first) object from last function

Tags: javascript, reference, this, element

I am really sorry if this has already been asked; as you can tell by the title, I have been having a terrible time trying to word the search term for this.

You can use `this` to reference the `Element` a function is being called from. For example:

```
Element.prototype.getElement = function(){
    return this;
}
```

If you call this function with:

`document.body.getElement();`

It would return the `<body>` Element.

Now, how from within my function, would I reference `document`?

```
Element.prototype.returnFirstElement = function(){

}
```

`document.body.getElement().getFirstElement();`

I want to always reference the very top Element/Object from my statement. Is this possible?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: you can use : firstChild http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_firstchild.asp

Comment: You have misunderstood the question. I want to reference `MyDiv` in `MyDiv.getContainer().setSticky()` from `setSticky()` for example.

Comment: MyDiv in MyDiv.getContainer().setSticky() from setSticky() - not able to understand

Comment: are you talking about `document.documentElement;` ?

Comment: No! In JS we create long strings of properties and functions connected with the `.` property accessor. I would like to reference the first one, in  my statement, regardless which one it is. For example I would like to reference `myDiv` from within `myDiv.someProp.myFunc()`.